# Panel has really wide clock

Tags: 10.04, panel, kde, kubuntu, widgets

On starting my Kubuntu 10.04 the other day I got something like this [image]

How do I make the clock a normal size so that there is room for my windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a corrupted config file. Try to create a new panel and drag the widgets from one panel to another. If that doesn't help, create  a new panel and add new widgets. If that doesn't help, then you might need to delete plasma config files (make a backup).

```
rm -f ~/.kde/share/config/plasmarc    
rm -f ~/.kde/share/config/plasma-appletsrc
```

Comment: @steevc Task Manager widget